# Get first non null object, non empty string field value from a list

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I have a

```
List<ClassA> listOfClassA;
```

ClassA contains another object let say insideObj. I want to fetch the first instance of insideObj which is non null, and contains a non empty field which is a string. Currently i am doing

```
for (ClassA objA : listOfClassA) {
        if(objA.getInsideObj() != null && !objA.getInsideObj().getName().isEmpty())
            return objA.getInsideObj().getName();
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this in Java 8?

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
listOfClassA.stream()
  .map(ClassA::getInsideObj)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .map(ClassB::getName)
  .filter(this::isNotEmpty)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(null);

boolean isNotEmpty (String s) {
  return s != null && !s.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Will this return a null if its unable to find a non null insideObj() or a insideObj with a non empty name string?

Comment: Thanks, however when i put a return before your code snippet it says "The method orElse(null) is undefined for the type Stream<String>". Technically i just want to return the very first valid occurence of getName

Comment: @Saad Did you put the `findFirst`, I forgot first time.

Comment: Sorry i did findAny(). Now its giving error The method filter(Predicate<? super String>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (this::isEmpty)

Comment: @Saad isEmpty is a method you have to write which does `return s !- null and !s.isEmpty();`

Comment: *contains a non empty field which is a string.* ... you can use `String::isEmpty`

Comment: Since the original loop did not contain any code handling a `null` name, you don’t need such an `isNotEmpty` method for the Stream solution either.

Comment: @Holger  true, but why take the risk of throwing a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @fastcodejava why take the risk of continuing with a `null` at a place that is supposed to be non-`null`? To end up polluting the entire application with `null`-checks at every reference variable?

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like so,

```
String firstInsideName = listOfClassA.stream()
    .map(ClassA::getInsideObj)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(InsideObj::getName)
    .filter(n -> !n.isEmpty())
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Predicate<ObjA> objAfilter = objA -> Objects.nonNull(objA.getInsideObj()) && Objects.nonNull(objA.getInsideObj().getName()) && !objA.getInsideObj().getName().isEmpty();

String firstInsideName = listOfClassA.stream()
    .filter(objAfilter)
    .map(ClassA::getInsideObj)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```